# Alfresco Process Services 1.*-2.* migration

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to migrate to Alfresco Process Services 2.3.2 from 1.*

There is a property in the [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/process-services/latest/upgrade/) about *activiti.engine5.enabled* property I don't understand how to set. The documentation does not make sense:
*Before you upgrade from 1.x to 2.x you must set the activiti.engine5.enabled property to **true** in the activiti-app.properties file.
Once you have upgraded from 1.x to 2.x you must set the activiti.engine5.enabled property to **true** in the activiti-app.properties file.*

It says to set it to true before the upgrade and after the upgrade.
Isn't it a mistake? Does anyone know how to set up this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is enough to set `activiti.engine5.enabled` to `true` in the moment of the upgrade.